# Why is it that when I write "u"==("a" or "e" or "i"or "o" or "u") in Python that I get False? Isn't "u" in the "a" or "e" or "i"or "o" or "u"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am confused on why Python does not see that "u" is in the characters I just put.

I wrote the following:

```
"u"==("a" or "e" or "i"or "o" or "u")
```

Comment: Voting to reopen. The OP doesn't ask how to check it, but asks about the logic behind a very specific case.

Comment: Short version: `or` short-circuits, returning the first truthy value. So what you wrote determines that `"a"` is truthy, and the whole parenthetical "returns" `"a"`, rendering the final test `"u" == "a"`.

Comment: @RoboRobok: I added another duplicate that asks about the why of this behavior.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks, that second one suits well enough.

Comment: @ShadowRanger so how can I get the value of true out of this statement?

Comment: @Shyam See [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149/4518341) on "How to test multiple variables against a value?". In short, `"u" in {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}`.